# Rails ActiveRelation to hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, active-relation

I need to hashify ActiveRelation! For example
I have such AR

```
arel = MyClass.page(options[:page]).per(options[:per])
```

Is here a way simple to create hash with primary keys of MyTable as keys in hash

Ex1:

```
[#<Object id: 44, name: "name44" >, #<Object id: 2, name: "name2" >, #<Object id: 110, name: "name110">]
=>
{44=>"name44", 2=>"name2",110=>"name110"}
```

Ex2:

```
[#<Object id: 44, name: "name44" >, #<Object id: 2, name: "name2" >, #<Object id: 110, name: "name110">]
=>
{44=>{:id=>44, :name=>"name44", 2=>{:id=>2,:name=>"name2"},110=>{:id=>110,:name=>"name110"}}
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `index_by`:

```
MyClass.limit(20).all.index_by(&:id)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by

Comment: Helped me a lot ! Thx

Answer (score 2):

You could do that manually, there is no function defined in Array class.

```
hsh = {}
objects.each { |u| hsh.merge!({ u.id => { :name => u.name } })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `serializable_hash`, [documented here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#method-i-serializable_hash).